# React semantic ui dropdown Remote fetch

Tags: reactjs, fetch, dropdown, semantic-ui

we like to use Dropdown with multi and search. On the onSearchChange we fetch data. But if we start a new search, already selected items disappear....?!

This is my code:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        field1: [], 
        options: [],
        isFetching: false
    }
  }


  handleDropdown = (event, data)  => { 
    this.setState({ field1: data.value});
  }

  handleSearchDropdown = (e, { searchQuery }) => {
    this.setState({ isFetching: true })
    fetch(`${'/searchgrants?query='}${searchQuery}`)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then(dataList => {
        this.setState({ options: dataList , isFetching: false});
        });
  }


  render() {
    return (
     <Form.Field
        control={Dropdown}
        onChange={this.handleDropdown}
        options={this.state.options}
        value={this.state.field1}
        fluid
        search
        selection
        required
        minCharacters={1}
        onSearchChange={this.handleSearchDropdown}
        multiple  
        loading={this.state.isFetching}
      />
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to want to preserve previous state of your data then you just need to do add `this.state.options` in `setState` and deconstruct it.

```
this.setState({ options: [...this.state.options, ...dataList] , isFetching: false});
```